# RSpec Tagging: Can I mix inclusions and exclusions on the same tag?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tags

Let's say I have the following rspec examples:

```
it "doesn't require a user account" do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type A", requires_user: "A" do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type B", requires_user: "B" do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type C", requires_user: "C" do
  ...
end
```

I have an environment that cannot run tests that require users of type "B" or "C", but is fine with running tests that either don't require a special user or only require type "A". Is it possible to specify tag options that will run the tests I want against that environment? I tried to combine multiple tags in the following way:

```
rspec spec --tag ~requires_user:B --tag ~requires_user:C
```

But this did not have the desired result. It appears that you can only provide one tag filter for a given tag name/key, and only the last `requires_user` tag was processed:

```
rspec spec --tag ~requires_user:B --tag ~requires_user:C
Run options:
  exclude {:requires_user=>"C"}
```

This seems to shut down most of the other ideas that came to mind, since it means I can't use inclusions instead (which would require including "A" and also including tests that have no `requires_user` tag at all, and I'm not even sure if it's possible to do the latter) and adding a `requires_user: "none"` tag wouldn't really help the situation.

Is there some way to do it using a key/value tag, or do I have to separate them all out and turn them into binary tags, i.e.

```
it "doesn't require a user account" do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type A", requires_user_A: true do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type B", requires_user_B: true do
  ...
end

it "requires user of type C", requires_user_C: true do
  ...
end
```

Maybe it's better that way, since it isn't impossible that a new test will require multiple user types. But in general I think there are tags that will have mutually exclusive values, that is, if it's A it can't be B or C, etc, and I would naturally want to use key/value pairs to describe that. If it limits my ability to execute the tests I want, though, that would be a problem.

Comment: Do you have to use the `tags` command line option or would you be willing to use the `RSpec.configure`?

Comment: @JustinKo It's possible, but I'd like to be able to use the command line. I definitely want someone to be able to add or remove tags without too much trouble for a given run. These tests will eventually be run by Jenkins, which I imagine could edit the file that contains the `RSpec.configure` bits, but that'd be a bit clunky and wouldn't work for local execution.

At the moment, I've switched to binary for this case, which I think is actually better. But it's still an open question if I hit a tag that really should be key:value.